# Split an array to smaller arrays according to specific patterns in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to split an array of double values into smaller chunks of array...For example lets say I have an infinite sized array test = { x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7,... } and I want to split them into 3 separate array with a={x0,x3,x6,x9,...}, b={x1,x4,x7,x10,..} and c={x2,x5,x8,x11,..}..

I hv tried,but it is not running..Im not sure what is the error ? And is there an easier way to do this ?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] test = { 0.2, 1.4, 2.45, 3.66, 4.34, 5.8, 6.9, 7.56, 8.899, 9.232, 10.1, 11.1, 12.45,13.87,14.8,15.78};
        double[] array = double [0];
        double[] array1 = double [0];
        double[] array2 = double [0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.Length; j=j+3)
            {
                array[i] = test[j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < test.Length; j = j + 3)
            {
                array1[i] = test[j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < test.Length; j = j + 3)
            {
                array2[i] = test[j];
            }
        }

        foreach (int item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is probably an index out of range error right  That `j=j+3` thing looks dubious?  Why not try the linq method `Take` and `Skip`.  Very easy to use.

Comment: Your code won't compile in the first place because that's not a correct way to allocate an array.

Comment: Also, indexes are 0 based, but `length` is 1 based.  So you were off by one.  Here is your code executing.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/dCn9yY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough LINQ provide real elegant solutions to your problem, they are kind of overkill. Besides, I think you need to grasp some basic concepts first before trying and using more advanced features of c#.

First:

```
double[] array = double [0];
```

What actually does, is create an empty array of doubles, in fact, it will give you a syntax error, your code should read `double[] array = new double [0];`. What you really want is to use a List:

```
List<double> array = new List<double>();
```

That will create the collection you are really looking for. To append items to this collection, use the following (also, eliminate the outer loop, it should not be there):

```
for (int j = 0; j < test.Length; j = j + 3)
{
    array.Add(test[j]);
}
```

Your final foreach loop should not be reading ints, it should be reading doubles

```
foreach (double item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Apply those changes and your code will work as expected :).

Finally, you don't need 3 separate loops to do the work, you could fill the 3 arrays (or any number of arrays) in a single loop, but that one is left to you.

Comment: How can I fill the 3 arrays (or any number of arrays) in a single loop ? Can U pls show me..Im quite new to C#

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < test.Length; /* No increment here */)
{
    array.Add(test[j]);
    j++;
    array1.Add(test[j]);
    j++;
    array2.Add(test[j]);
    j++;
    ....
    arrayN.Add(test[j]);
    j++;
}`

You could also have the arrays stored in another array (something like a matrix). to process that you would need another nested loop...

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ method `Where` has an overload with an index parameter, you can use `Skip`, that overload and the modulus operator to achieve this:

```
double[] test = { 0.2, 1.4, 2.45, 3.66, 4.34, 5.8, 6.9, 7.56, 8.899, 9.232, 10.1, 11.1, 12.45, 13.87, 14.8, 15.78 };

var first = test.Skip(0).Where((x, i) => i%3 == 0);
var second = test.Skip(1).Where((x, i) => i%3 == 0);
var third = test.Skip(2).Where((x, i) => i%3 == 0);
```

In the example, `i` is the item's index. Doing `i % 3` returns every third item. The code above produces collections of type `IEnumerable<double>`. If you need `double[]` then call `ToArray` on each one.

As a warning, if you're going to be iterating each of these results multiple times, you'll want to call `ToArray` or `ToList` on each one. If you don't, the `test` array will be iterated through every single time and which is very inefficient.

Comment: Things you may want to mention here- this doesn't produce an array as output, unless you tack a `.ToArray()` on the end.  This actually re-iterates the source array every time `first` is evaluated, which in real life is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably harness the power of linq like so:

```
double[] test = { 0.2, 1.4, 2.45, 3.66, 4.34, 5.8, 6.9, 7.56, 8.899, 9.232, 10.1, 11.1, 12.45, 13.87, 14.8, 15.78 };
var numberOfArrays = 3;

var sublists = test.Select((i, idx) => new { Item = i, Index = idx })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index % numberOfArrays)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Item).ToArray())
            .ToList();
```

The solution above allows you to specify the number of arrays, and it will split the original array into a list of arrays accordingly. This is achieved by using the modulus operator, denoted by the `%` sign.

Answer (score 0):

A few errors here:

This means "create an array zero items long".  Considering that you want to populate these arrays, you should use a number greater than zero.  `Test.length / 3` seems the right number in your example.

```
double[] array = double [0]; // This is wrong

// Try this instead:

var array = new double[test.Length / 3]; // div 3 because you have 3 output arrays
```

Then here, you want to limit your outer loop to array.Length, not test.Length:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = test[i*3];
    }
```